# Capture password change at active directory controller

Tags: c#, .net

I've seen a couple of software packages run as a service on an active directory controller which captures a password change initiated by a user. My application needs to know what the newly changed password is for a user to propagate across other systems.  Does anyone know how this is done?  Thanks.

BTW, I'm writing in C#, but other .net languages are welcome.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757490/tracking-changes-in-the-active-directory-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a [Password Filter](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20and%20Passwords) on the Active Directory Server, specifically the [PasswordChangeNotify callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Unfortunately to [use one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722496%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) you must make a COM Server DLL which really shouldn't be written in .NET<sup>†</sup>.

However, there is a 2nd option. There is a open source password filter I have used in the past that worked well called [Password Hook](http://sourceforge.net/projects/passwdhk/). That password filter will launch a 2nd program (as defined in the registry) and pass in the password info as command line arguments (like your .NET program to update the other services of the password change).

---

<sup>†: I saw a good posting here on SO on why you should not use .NET in windows components when I was looking in to password stuff a year ago, but I can't find it again. If anyone else can find it, please feel free to edit in the link</sup>

Comment: Thanks; I just looked at the password hook.  While I'm not going to be able to use it; it will provide guidance in writing this.  Also, the above link from Arshad contains another link in how to do this with C#.  It looks like the password hook program is using VC++ .net....  I dug around a while yesterday and couldn't find any reason why not to write this in .net.  I would be interested in reading that though if it were out there somewhere.