# Active Directory - post user updates to external service

Tags: asp.net, .net, active-directory

I'd like to build a .net service to sync Active Directory user details to a website database.  Specifically I'm interested in details of how to configure Active Directory to push user update details when a change is made in Active Directory.  eg. If a user is deactivated in Active Directory then I want to deactivate the user on the website.  If a user is added to AD then I want to add the user to the website.

The website database is a completely separate repository to AD.  So if, for example, a user is added to AD then the website needs all the details of the new user so it can then replicate the user's details in the website's database.

I've googled around a fair amount and haven't found any details about configuring AD to notify changes like this.

Comment: Possibly already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002606/registering-change-notification-with-active-directory-using-c-sharp

Comment: That looks very promising, I'll check it out. Thanks!