# Possible to create Skype for business account for AD User by adding to AD group?

Tags: active-directory, skype-for-business

I need to create Skype for Business accounts for AD users with a third-party tool. I am looking for a different solution besides calling PowerShell script. One solution came to my mind which is adding Active Directory user to Active Directory group.

My question is that is it possible to manage accounts by adding/removing to the AD group?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you have a working PS script, you should figure out what it is using. But I don't think that simple group membership would be enough - the server manages many things for an account, as does Exchange for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention if this is on-prem or online, but I don't think it matters. In both cases, the only way to programmatically add a user to Skype for Business is with PowerShell.

I've written C# code to create SfB accounts, and I've had to call PowerShell commands from C#. That is a pain. I hate it. But here we are.

If you want to automatically add users to SfB when they are added to an AD group, then you will need to write code to monitor the membership of that group and add users. You can do this with a scheduled task that runs a PowerShell script, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen the active directory notifications.And then create sfb user and enable it.
You can get help from below post about active directory notifications.

[Active Directory Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002606/registering-change-notification-with-active-directory-using-c-sharp)